# Can an LR(1) parser parse this grammar?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, lr-grammar

I have the following CFG that I'd like to parse with an LR(1) parser:

> S → A | B
>
> A  → ε | A
>
> B  → ε |B

Can an LR(1) parser parse this grammar? If so, can you show me the parse table? If not, why not and how can you tell?

Comment: See [Canonical LR parser on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser) - any insight? How does LR(1) differ from LR(0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an LR(1) parser cannot parse this grammar. LR(k) parsers can only parse unambiguous grammars, and this grammar is ambiguous (you can derive ε in infinitely many ways).

You can check this by building the configurating sets for the grammar, though that's going to be pretty boring. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer,how do i check from sets?Is it something like that,if i cant create sets it is not parseable if i can it is parseable?

Comment: @DRoW You probably should read up more on LR parsing if you're not familiar with configurating sets, since they're fundamental to how the parser works. Start with LR(0) parsing first if you haven't seen configurating sets, since they're a lot easier to work with.

Comment: actually i read a lot of resource about lr parsing ,i just see only item sets,parse table and parsing from table.can u send me link for that include configurating sets?

Comment: i searched it ,it's same as item sets just different naming :)